# How to make multiple http calls in the same function with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, angular8

**What I want to achieve:**
Make calls from component.ts to the service this.getMatches, in this.getMatches I have to make some API calls and work with the data I get
before it gets pushed to the array

**What I did:**
1: The function runs and send "gameId" as an argument to the function this.getmatches. I get an array of every match with all data that I pushed to every single match
2: I was able to find a method that worked after many tries, but it failed when it returning to the array

**The problem:**
Sometimes it returns the same match, I noticed it happens when I add the "swtichmap" operator.

[return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rmyX.png)

**Services.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SummonerService {

  constructor( private http:HttpClient ) { }

  summonerName
  dataMatch
  matchParticipants
  matchHistory = [];

    getSummoner(summonerName,regionId){
    this.summonerName = summonerName
   return this.http.get(`http://localhost:3000/summName/${summonerName}/${regionId}` )
  };

   getMatches(gameId){
     return this.http.get( `http://localhost:3000/match/${gameId}` 
     ).pipe(
       tap( (data:any) => {
         console.log(data.match);
         this.dataMatch = data.match
         this.matchParticipants = data.match.participants
        }) ,
       switchMap( data => {
         return this.http.get(`http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.5.1/data/en_US/summoner.json`)
       }),
       tap( (data:any) =>{


         let spellsObj = data.data;
         const spellsArray:Array<any>[] = [];

         Object.keys(spellsObj).forEach( key =>{

           let spell = spellsObj[key]

           spellsArray.push(spell)
          });

          this.matchParticipants.forEach( participants => {

            let spellId1:any = spellsArray.find( (spell:any) => spell.key === JSON.stringify(participants.spell1Id) );
            let spellId2:any = spellsArray.find( (spell:any) => spell.key === JSON.stringify(participants.spell2Id) );


            let spellId1Image = `http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.5.1/img/spell/${spellId1.id}.png`
            let spellId2Image = `http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/10.5.1/img/spell/${spellId2.id}.png`

            participants.spellId1Info = spellId1
            participants.spellId2Info = spellId2

            participants.spellId1Info.image = spellId1Image
            participants.spellId2Info.image = spellId2Image
    });
       }),
       map ( data =>{ 
          return this.dataMatch
         })
       )};
```

I put part of the code, but I need to make more calls like this .

```
 switchMap( data => {
         return this.http.get(`http://x.json`)
       }),
```

I don't know if the call here with the "switchmap" was done correctly either

**Component.ts**

```
onSubmit( ){

    this.summ.getSummoner( this.summoner.name,this.summoner.regionId )
    .pipe( 
      tap( (summoner:any) => this.matchHistory = summoner.matchHistory ),
      concatMap( (summoner:any) => {
        const observables = this.matchHistory
        .map( element => this.summ.getMatches(element.gameId));
          return forkJoin(observables)
      }),
      map( (matchesArray:any) => {
        let gameIdArray = this.matchHistory.map( element => element.gameId)

        this.matchesArray = matchesArray.sort((a, b) => {  
          return gameIdArray.indexOf(a.gameId) - gameIdArray.indexOf(b.gameId);
        });
        return matchesArray
      })
      ) .subscribe();
```

Comment: Could you do a simple stackblitz that demonstrates your issue that we could take a look at?

Answer (score 1):

`switchMap` here looks pretty ok to me, if you are not sure about that, feel free to check out my blog post about this topic: https://dev.to/rxjs/about-switchmap-and-friends-2jmm.

If you want to make multiple requests you need to apply a combination operator within the `switchMap`, probably either `merge` or `forkJoin`. The code could look like this:

```
 switchMap( data => merge(
    this.http.get(`http://x.json`),
    this.http.get(`http://y.json`),
    this.http.get(`http://z.json`)
)),
```

So the question is which of those you want to use:

You want to use [merge](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/merge) when you don't really care if the other HTTP calls are already completed. You will get a new value emited after the switchMap every time one of those HTTP requests return a response and you will also only get that very response.

You want to use [forkJoin](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) when you care that all HTTP calls are completed before you go one. You will also get an Array of HTTP responses which you can use to continue the processing.